# When i am clicking submit button it shows "object not found" error

Tags: php, laravel

I have made a form to submit user data but when I am clicking submit button it shows an error "Object not found"

View file`

```
@extends('layout')

   @section('content')
    <h1 class="title">Simple Form</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/projects">
    @csrf
        <div class="field">
        <label class="label" for="name">Name</label>

        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" class="input" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label class="label" for="email">E-mail</label>

        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" class="input" name="email" placeholder="Enter E-mail Address">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label class="label" for="pincode">Pincode</label>

        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" class="input" name="pincode" placeholder="Enter Pincode">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
@endsection
```

Controller file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Project;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ATGController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('projects.index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('projects.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        return request()->all();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Project $project)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Project $project)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Project  $project
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Project $project)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Route file

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/projects','ATGController@index');
Route::get('/projects/create','ATGController@create');
Route::post('/projects','ATGController@store');
```

Layout file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ATG</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error. 
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.7

Comment: What exact error do you get? `404` or `Object Not Found`?

Comment: Object not found

Comment: All looks to be good. What laravel version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not to use a **/** before a url. 
web.php:

```
Route::post('projects','ATGController@store');
```

view file:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('projects') }}">
```

*If this does not resolve the issue kindly check your app_url in your .env file.*